# Driving a quantum system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator

I don't understand the mathematical form of an external driving force on a quantum system. For example, say we were driving a quantum harmonic oscillator. You would have the Hamiltonian for the quantum harmonic oscillator plus the driving term which has the form of something like $E(a + a^{\dagger})$ (where $E$ is the driving strength).

Why does the driving term have this form?

Comment: For a harmonic oscillator $\sqrt{2} a^\dagger=\hat{x}-i \hat{p}$, and $\sqrt{2} a=\hat{x}+i \hat{p}$, i.e. $a+a^\dagger\propto \hat{x}$, so your excitation is just equal to $E \hat{x}$

Comment: @Pavlo.B.How does adding a drive term lead to excitation? I imagine it has to do with the fact that a† excites the quantum state, but what about a? Would this not de-excite a given quantum state as well?

Comment: One excites the ground state, but the other one kills it (i.e. gives zero), so they do not compensate each other

Comment: @Pavlo.B. Are there any sources you recommend that introduce the notion of a external drive in a quantum system?

Comment: I am not sure, any textbook should do it. For instance, Sakurai's "modern quantum mechanics". In your case though adding term $E\hat{x}$ to Hamiltonian is equivalent to adding uniform electric field (or, constant force), because that's how potential in the uniform electric field looks like